# Why / How to fix navigation button for shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to code an app that has a main menu with tabs and, then, one of the tabs to have tabs of its own. (like a nested list). Within this app, I am trying to include forward and backward buttons to progress through the app (next page, previous page). The next page buttons work fine, but the previous page buttons do not work (except the very first occurrence which is extra weird). I cannot figure out why. Code below to reproduce.

```
ui <- fluidPage( # doesn't matter if this is removed
  # doesn't matter if this is changed to navlistPanel()
  navbarPage(title = "app", id = 'mainpage', selected = "first",

             tabPanel(title = "first", value = "first",

                      navlistPanel(id = "first_sublist", selected = "firstfirst",
                      # tabsetPanel(id = "first_sublist", selected = "firstfirst",
                                   tabPanel(title = "firstfirst", value = "firstfirst",

                                            fluidRow(column(6, ""),
                                                     column(6, align = "center", actionButton(inputId = 'goto_firstsecond', label = div('Advance to firstsecond', icon('angle-double-right'))))
                                            )

                                   ),
                                   tabPanel(title = "firstsecond", value = "firstsecond",
                                            "This one works.",

                                            fluidRow(column(6, align = "center", actionButton(inputId = 'goto_firstfirst', label = 'Return to firstfirst', icon = icon('angle-double-left'))),
                                                     column(6, align = "center", actionButton(inputId = 'goto_firstthird', label = div('Advance to firstthird', icon('angle-double-right'))))
                                            )

                                   ),
                                   tabPanel(title = "firstthird", value = "firstthird",
                                            "This one does not work.",

                                            fluidRow(column(6, align = "center", actionButton(inputId = 'goto_firstsecond', label = 'Return to firstsecond', icon = icon('angle-double-left'))),
                                                     column(6, align = "center", actionButton(inputId = 'goto_firstfourth', label = div('Advance to firstfourth', icon('angle-double-right'))))
                                            )

                                   ),
                                   tabPanel(title = "firstfourth", value = "firstfourth",
                                            "This one does not work.",

                                            fluidRow(column(6, align = "center", actionButton(inputId = 'goto_firstthird', label = 'Return to firstthird', icon = icon('angle-double-left'))),
                                                     column(6, align = "center", actionButton(inputId = 'goto_firstfifth', label = div('Advance to firstfifth', icon('angle-double-right'))))
                                            )

                                   ),
                                   tabPanel(title = "firstfifth", value = "firstfifth",
                                            "This one does not work.",

                                            fluidRow(column(6, align = "center", actionButton(inputId = 'goto_firstfourth', label = 'Return to firstfourth', icon = icon('angle-double-left'))),
                                                     column(6, align = "center", "")
                                            )
                                   )
                      )

             ),

             tabPanel("second",  value = "second"

             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    switch_page <- function(i) {
      # doesn't work for either
      updateNavlistPanel(inputId = "first_sublist", selected = my.pages[i])
      # updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "first_sublist", selected = my.pages[i])
    }

    my.pages <- c("firstfirst", "firstsecond", "firstthird", "firstfourth", "firstfifth")

    observeEvent(input$goto_firstfirst, switch_page(1))
    observeEvent(input$goto_firstsecond, switch_page(2))
    observeEvent(input$goto_firstthird, switch_page(3))
    observeEvent(input$goto_firstfourth, switch_page(4))
    observeEvent(input$goto_firstfifth, switch_page(5))




  # tried coding this way too
  # observeEvent(input$goto_firstfirst, {
  #   updateNavlistPanel(inputId = "first_sublist",
  #                      selected = "firstfirst")
  # })
  #
  # observeEvent(input$goto_firstsecond, {
  #   updateNavlistPanel(inputId = "first_sublist",
  #                      selected = "firstsecond")
  # })
  #
  # observeEvent(input$goto_firstthird, {
  #   updateNavlistPanel(inputId = "first_sublist",
  #                      selected = "firstthird")
  # })
  #
  # observeEvent(input$goto_firstfourth, {
  #   updateNavlistPanel(inputId = "first_sublist",
  #                      selected = "firstfourth")
  # })
  #
  # observeEvent(input$goto_firstfifth, {
  #   updateNavlistPanel(inputId = "first_sublist",
  #                      selected = "firstfifth")
  # })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It does work to add another actionButton() specific to the previous page. I guess the actionbuttons are one and done. I will search a way to make one work...

Comment: Are you not getting a big error "updateNavlistPanel: argument "session" is missing, with no default"? You don't seem to be passing `session` to `updateNavlistPanel`

Comment: Also you seem to be creating buttons with duplicate IDs. IDs should be unquiet across all objects, ie, you can only have one button with `inputId="goto_firstsecond"`.

Comment: No error with the session argument missing. I think the duplicate IDs is the issue. Thank you. I had hoped to reference the same process (i.e., go to the same page) with two separate buttons (i.e., next and previous). I guess it is not possible. Or, perhaps, I need to do a dynamic button? May be unnecessary. Much simpler to code an additional process.

Answer (score 0):

@MrFlick pointed out error with duplicated IDs.

Solution is to have one ID per `actionButton()`. Then, I can use both `actionButton()` IDs within the same `observeEvent(ID1 | ID2, {})`.

Comment: Also, would need the ignoreInit = TRUE argument